# Quadcopter controller/autopilot with permissive license

Tags: open-source, automation

Is there an open source quadcopter controller (with or without autopilot) software package (that may run on some given HW) with permissive license (public domain, MIT, BSD etc.) that could be used in closed source projects?

The projects I am aware of all have a copyleft license (GPS): [ArduPilot/APM](http://ardupilot.org/), [LibrePilot](http://www.librepilot.org/) (formerly OpenPilot), [AeroQuad](http://aeroquad.com/) and [Cleanflight](http://cleanflight.com).